# Do domestic flights to Mumbai now go directly to international terminal?

Tags: airports, international-travel, domestic-travel, mumbai

I haven't traveled back to India since couple of years now. My mother is visiting me next month. Her flight is from Rajkot to Mumbai (Jet Airways Domestic flight) and than a connecting flight from Mumbai to Singapore(Also Jet Airways).

When I used to travel in the same flight I had to take an internal bus transfer from Mumbai domestic to international terminal to get to my international flight. One of my friend told me recently that this has changed now. The flight would directly go to the International terminal and then you get to your gate for the connecting flight.

Is this true? Do you no longer need to move between Mumbai airport terminals via buses?

Comment: There seems to be only one airport in Mumbai. Did you mean "terminal" instead of "airport"?

Comment: Yes if that's the right choice of words. The new CSI airport wasn't built when I was in Mumbai. There used to be the old Santa cruz airport if I remember correctly and the new CSI built later on. I was told that domestic and international were 5kms apart hence the bus transfers were necessary. IS this no longer the case? Have the two terminal been merged?

Comment: As per Wikipedia, Mumbai airport has two terminals, one is purely domestic and the other is both domestic and international. Usually, which terminal your flight uses is indicated on the ticket.

Comment: Thank you for your effort.. I already know that there are two terminals.. I just need to know if A person needs to take bus for transfer from one domestic terminal to international or not ...

Comment: You really need to be clearer in your question about what *exactly* you want to know. If the question is "how do you go from one terminal to the other at Mumbai airport", then it should say that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are flying with Jet Airways, Air Vistara or Air India only you will land on international airport in Mumbai. For rest you have to take the Bus internally.